# Get specific keys in multiple object in Array Node JS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I have an example code below :

```
z = [] //To get all the Id    
x = [
        {
           _id: "12345",
           name: "A"      
        },
        {
           _id: "67890",
           name: "B"
        }
    ]
```

The question is how I can get all the "_id" from "x" and save it to "z". So the results like this:

```
z = ["12345", "67890"]
```

Any answer would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**

```js
var  x = [
        {
           "_id": "12345",
           "name": "A"      
        },
        {
           "_id": "67890",
           "name": "B"
        }
    ];
var result = x.map(a => a._id);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
   
const x = [{
    _id: "12345",
    name: "A"
  },
  {
    _id: "67890",
    name: "B"
  }
]

const z = x.map(o => o._id);

console.log(z)
```